# how to reset seconds to zero in swift whilst timer running

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

Hi guys I've done a simple timer in Swift. All is well apart from when the seconds reach 59 seconds instead of going back to zero they just carry on going. Would someone would be able to point out where I'm going wrong and why this is happening?

this is my code :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var startTime = NSTimeInterval()
var timer = NSTimer()
var isRunning = false

func updateTime() {

    var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    var elapsedTime : NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time

    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime - (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time

    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)


    //fraction of milliseconds

    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutues, seconds and milliseconds, store
    // as string constants

    let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes): "0" + String(minutes)

    let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds): "0" + String(seconds)

    let strFraction = fraction > 9 ? String(fraction): "0" + String(fraction)

    //concatonate mins, seoncds and milliseconds, assign to UILable timercount

    TimerCount.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds):\(strFraction)"

}



@IBOutlet weak var TimerCount: UILabel!


@IBAction func StartButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !timer.valid {

        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }

}


@IBAction func StopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}




@IBAction func ResetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer.invalidate()
        TimerCount.text = "00:00:00"

}
```

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the code to create the string by using the format string, e.g. `TimerCount.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds, fraction)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple typo.

```
elapsedTime - (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
```

Should be:

```
elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
```

Comment: Aw man been looking at the code too long I think, yep thats in thanks for your help :-)